# Getting list from Neo4j query

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I want to create a json of the children of a node. I am using this command to get all the children of a particular node:

```
match(t:TAG)<-[children:CHILD_OF]-(subtag:TAG) where t.name="brand" 
return t.eid as parent, collect(subtag.eid) as child
```

I get my result like this:

```
6aada019f7312fb1    [967b5461b2ff7c0b, a81e1772e4f9f7ef, 3dfbbd025548c0972a372a88e7de626af, 2009a1e160299c775d2ff15786ce33208, 2342ee1b2d940ef949442445eff52081c, 0b0f878f-5061-48e9-90db-8c64aa9f8982, 81692c4c-8acb-4aea-b985-ae493a1b9b67, e21c063c-7432-4094-85ac-16bf02f92a8e, 6fc485a0-5a05-49d0-a061-091077a95af7]
```

I now want to access the list of the children in java.

```
 String query = "match(t:TAG)<-[children:CHILD_OF]-(subtag:TAG) where t.name=\"brand\" return t.name as parent, subtag.name as child";
        Iterable<Map<String, Object>> itr = Neo4j.queryLagData(query, null);
 for(Map m : itr){
            String parent = (String)m.get("parent");
            String children = (String)m.get("child");

        }
```

Should I be splitting the string of the children now? Or is there a method that will give me a list of the children directly or a method that will give me the children as a json directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

. Your "child" field should be a List of Strings.
. you should use a parameter for the tag name, like {name} 
. and you can combine the iteration and querying

```
String query = "match(t:TAG)<-[children:CHILD_OF]-(subtag:TAG) where t.name={name} "+
               "return t.name as parent, collect(subtag.name) as children";
for(Map row : Neo4j.queryLagData(query, singletonMap("name","brand"))) {
    String parent = (String)row.get("parent");
    List<String> children = (List<String>)row.get("children");
}
```

Comment: How can I pass the parameters in the neo4j browser?